# SQL Server LIKE clause issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may something really simple I'm overlooking, but it's driving me nuts.

The basic gist is that I have a very simple table in SQL Server 2014, called Products, which contains some ProductNames column (nvarchar(max)). I put in some test strings, such as

```
Caly
Calyd
Cali
Cal
Taly
Blical
Blacaly
```

and I'm executing a very simple SELECT on this table:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductName LIKE '%Cal%'
```

and here's the thing, I'm only getting back these results

```
Cali
Cal
Blical
```

**Notice the missing Caly, and Blacaly**. But if I search for '%Caly%', I get back the expected results:

```
Caly
Calyd
Blacaly
```

Or if I search for '%Ca%', again, as expected:

```
Caly
Calyd
Cali
Cal
Blical
Blacaly
```

So really, what gives, I'm at a total loss here. Is 'Cal' some kind of weird easter egg word? Are gnomes eating my results, or what?

(Btw,I tried the same thing out in MySQL, just as a test, it works as expected there.)

Comment: What collation do you use?

Comment: It's Hungarian_CI_AS.

Comment: It's surely a collation issue. See here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b2360/1

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 it works anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using Hungarian_CI_AS collation. In [Hungarian alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_alphabet) digraph ['ly'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_ly) is a separate letter.

So for example "Caly" is a 3-letter word - 'C', 'a', 'ly'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This never crossed my mind. Search a bit, the recommended solution in this case  is to change to collation to Hungarian_Technical_CI_AS.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your collation, if you look at the Hungarian collation Ly is a character:

[Hungarian Collation Chart](http://collation-charts.org/mssql/mssql.040E.1250.Hungarian_CI_AS.html)

And so the like will behave differently, if you really want to treat the data in the Hungarian collated column differently, as in like the Latin1 collation, then you have to tell SQL server this during the select:

```
SELECT *
FROM Products
WHERE ProductName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS LIKE '%Cal%'
```